# Understanding flexbox in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am learning CSS by creating a website and came along flexbox which seem useful for designing the layout of the website. So far I have created the basic header/main/footer grid layout in a column, but was wondering how I would go about, say, making a grid such as the following:

```
____________________
|         |         |
|         |         |
| image 1 | image 2 |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|_________|_________|
|_______footer______|
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  object-fit: contain;
}


<div class="flex-container">
  <div> <img src="image1.jpg" alt="update"></div>
  <div> <img src="image2.jpg" alt="update"></div>
</div>
```

which is contained inside:

```
<body class="grid" style="margin: auto;">

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 50%;

}
```

The images don't fit inside the body but overflow the width and height. I've tried setting the max width/height but they still overflow. Any ideas?

*Note the footer is separate to the image flexboxes but I included it for illustration

Comment: Of course. Haven't you had a look at the thousands of examples to be found? It may require nesting of grid structure, but that's a very common scenario. FYI, your question is off-topic without some markup to show your attempt, leaving the question too broad for a Q&A format.

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't include code because mine is pretty irrelevant, its just a 2x1 box atm i.e  | | |

Comment: @Paulie_D I've edited the question with code and decided that i only want 2 pictures next to each other, is the question better now?

Answer (score -1):

First of all I can only recommend to read up on CSS Grid over at CSS-Tricks https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and doing the course by Wes Bos at https://cssgrid.io/ (it's free).

Second of all, yes, it is totally possible to have such a layout with CSS Grid.

Yet, I'd definitely think twice on using CSS Grid for something that trivial as having images stand next to each other, which they normally do in and of themselves (images are inline elements).

If you insist on using CSS Grid for this, then you could go this way:

```
<div class="images-grid">
    <img src="img1.xxx" />
    <img src="img2.xxx" />
    <img src="img3.xxx" />
</div>
```

and then throw `display: grid` on the div container.

Comment: This doesn't achieve the described layout.

Answer (score -1):

It's not so complicated once you master [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) a bit :

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

.main {
  border: #f00 solid 2px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.main .left,
.main .right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.main .left {
  border: #00f solid 2px;
}

.main .right {
  border: #008000 solid 2px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main .right .up,
.main .right .down {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.main .right .up {
  border: #000 solid 2px;
}

.main .right .down {
  border: #ffd700 solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="left"></div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="up"></div>
    <div class="down"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/PRoNYE?editors=1111)

Comment: Yay, a silent downvote, thank you so much, I can improve with that.